# How to set new windows to open in disconnected mode by default in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Let's say I have a query window open in SSMS. The window is connected to a SQL Server. If I open a new window then the new window opens with the same connection as the last opened window.

How to restrict that? I need the new window to open as disconnected by default. I shall connect to the server as per my need.

Otherwise, let's say the last window was connected to production. you opened a new window to run a query in the dev environment. But if you are not careful enough the query gets executed in production as the new window automatically took the connection of the last opened window i.e production.

Comment: Why not just be vigilant..? Or, if you want to open a new window connected to a specific instance and database, then select that database in the object explorer first.

Comment: You allow external connections to your production server(s)?

Comment: There's no option for this in SSMS afaik. However there *is* an option for connection colour-coding so you can easily see if you are connected to dev or production being green or red for example.

Comment: You could also just make sure if you want a new query window to always right-click on the desired server from either Object Explorer or Registered Servers and select *New Query*

Comment: Color coding can be setup in Connect To window by selecting Connection Properties tab and cheking "Use custom color" checkbox

Comment: Thank You all, especially Stu and Alex for the wok around. It definitely helps as the required feature is not available in SSMS.